# d3.select returns empty in ExtJs doc

Tags: extjs, extjs4, d3.js

I am using D3 to render into an ExtJs component from a Json data source.

from test.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            Ext.onReady(function(){
                Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',
                {
                    layout: 'fit',
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            html : 'There should be a test below this'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'testPanel',
                            xtype: 'xxxviewtest'
                        }
                    ]
                });
                d3.json("Test1.json", function(json) { Ext.getCmp ('testPanel').deliverJson (json); });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</head>
```

and Test.js:

```
Ext.define('xxx.view.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    alias: 'widget.xxxviewtest',

    deliverJson: function(json) {
        var target = d3.select("#" + this.id);
        if (target[0][0]) {
            // install svg element and draw
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

In simple test cases this is working fine, but in a more complex document case involving  tab panels and a lot of UI components, the call to d3.select in Test.js is returning an empty selection.

What do I need to do for this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "d3.select in Test.js is returning an empty selection", I think at that time the Ext components which you queried have not fully displayed. So I recommend moving the `d3.json(...)` into `render` event's handler to eliminate one possibility. If the issues still happen, we will find another way.

Comment: I moved the call to d3.json (...) into a button click handler in the Ext hierarchy and it works fine. I had a feeling it would be something like that, but I also (erroneously) thought the Ext.create (...) call would be synchronous WRT calls after it in the Ext.onReady (...) method.